# Is Google Cloud Storage expensive?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

It's not a technical question. I'm using Google Cloud as secondary backup solution. I synchronize some log files and a shared folder which contains Word and Excel files from office. All files are less than 75 GB.[image]

I've never used cloud copy of files yet. I use oDrive as client.

I've received a few invoices around 20 USD per month. But the last one is more than 60 USD and it seems quite expensive to me. There are cloud backup solutions for a few bucks for a year. Is it ok or do I need to find a cheaper solution?

If a thecnical question is a must so what Cloud Storage Class A Request -the most costly item- is? Is Coldline Storage was a bad decision for my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) contains prices and examples on how the calculation is done.

In your case the highest value is not related to the storage per se (described as “Cloud Storage Coldline Storage Europe”). Instead the Class A request are the operations you performed over the storage. They are described in the same document (i.e. inserts, updates, rewrites).  Their price varies depending on the storage type being used.

i.e.

$0.10 Nearline and Durable Reduced Availability x 10000

6.575.411 operations / 10000  x 0.10 = 65.75

You are certainly using one of the [recommended storage types for archival](https://cloud.google.com/storage/archival/) .If you have doubts on your invoices you can also contact [Cloud Billing Support team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/).

Comment: My operations seem way too much. Need to visit oDrive forums.